# Replace elements in matrix to make it symmetric using automated procedure

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, replacement

I am generating a matrix using

```
(mat2 = Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {4, 4}]) // MatrixForm
```

but would like to force Mathematica to make it symmetric. Thereby I am using

```
 mat2 //. {Subscript[a, 2, 1] -> Subscript[a, 1, 2]}
```

to replace $a_{21}$ with $a_{12}$. For the other elements, and also for higher order squares, is there an efficient way to automate this somehow?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply a rule using `Condition`:

```
mat2 /. Subscript[a, i_, j_] :> Subscript[a, j, i] /; j > i
```

giving

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a_{1,1} & a_{2,1} & a_{3,1} & a_{4,1} \\
 a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{3,2} & a_{4,2} \\
 a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & a_{4,3} \\
 a_{4,1} & a_{4,2} & a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 5):

You could define it with

```
Array[Subscript[a, Min[##], Max[##]] &, {4, 4}]
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the built-in matrix manipulation commmands

```
mat = Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {4, 4}];
LowerTriangularize[mat] + Transpose[LowerTriangularize[mat]] - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[mat]]
```

gives the same answer. This takes the lower triangular part and adds it to the transpose of itself, giving a symmetric matrix in which the diagonal entries have been doubled. Hence they are subtracted out.